# Generate RSA key-pair from "N", "E", "D" keys using crypto module

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa

i'm new to cryptography.

I'm creating the RSA key-pairs using `crypto.generateKeyPairSync()`

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 2048,
  publicExponent: 3,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs1',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs1',
    format: 'pem'
  }
})

console.log(publicKey)
console.log(privateKey)

// print "n", "e", "d" keys
```

This works fine but the i need to extract the `"n", "e", "d"` keys so that an other app can encrypt and decrypt the messages. It would be great if this is possible without any 3rd-party libraries only the native NodeJS crypto module.

Also if it's not possible to extract the `"n", "e", "d"` keys, would it be possible to create a new public and private key using existing `"n", "e", "d"` keys from an other app?

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine but the i need to extract the "n", "e", "d" keys so that an other app can encrypt and decrypt the messages. It would be great if this is possible without any 3rd-party libraries only the native NodeJS crypto module.

First of all, the modulus n, public exponent e and private exponent d are not keys, they are components that are used to make up a key. As an RSA key contains *at least* two components you need some kind of method to distinguish them from each other. You need some kind of data structure which separates the components, which is exactly what the PKCS#1 ASN.1 specifications provide. Just specifying that you will deliver an RSA key using a PEM formatted PKCS#1 should be enough.

The private key, as the name suggests, should really not be shared. There is no such thing as a shared private key after all. Keys are generated for one specific entity, and are usually kept where they are generated (possibly exempting encrypted backup).

If you use only n and d then you will probably leave out any generated CRT parameters for the private key, which means that in the best case the RSA key operations don't run. In the worst case the RSA implementation is extremely picky and won't run at all.

Finally, as the documentation correctly indicates, you should be using `'spki'` as output format (the public key as used within certificates, called the `SubjectPublicKeyIdentifier`, specified in the X.509 standards) and `'pkcs8'` as they contain an indication of the key **type** used. These are probably better supported by other applications than PKCS#1.

If they are not able to decode it themselves then simply copy the base 64 into [this site (online ASN.1 decoder)](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) and copy the relevant values. You can find the order of the values (for `'pkcs1'`) in the [PKCS#1 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-C).

Comment: How can i define the components (n, e, d) to generate a  new RSA public and private key? Can you please make an example i never really used the crypto module much. Also the other app uses pkcs1 and if i use spki are they still able to encrypt and decrypt the messages?

Comment: Well, if it looks for PKCS#1 and finds SPKI then no, it won't work. However, PKCS#1 public key is part of SPKI, so it is certainly possible to make it work. Why are you so desperate to extract the separate components if there are standardized ways of representing keys that contain all the components you might need?

Comment: i have all the components (n, e, d) but eventually i need to be able to encrypt and decrypt messages from and to the other app which uses the same components.

Comment: the way it works is: i send the diffiehellman prime and generator encrypted using rsa to the other app. the other app then decrypt the message and generates diffiehellman key and sends them back to me. then i generate the shared diffiehellman key and send them back to the other app. all messages are encrypted using rsa. so i need to be able to encrypt / decrypt messages using the components (n, e, d). im basically trying to make a handshake. i think there is also rc4 included somewhere but i dont know where this takes place. im really new to all this cryptography

Comment: You absolutely have no clue what you are doing, correct? That's not how DH works at all. You send the signed parameters, possibly including the public key to the other site, who verifies the parameters and performs the key agreement. You do this at both sides. As I was expecting, this is basically an XY-problem. Rethink, restart.

Comment: yes im new to this. it would be really helpful if you can show me a small example

Comment: You know, this could be tricky to explain easily. I did search for a good diagram to help me with this, but haven't found much. It is of course in my brain, but it may have to stay there for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library [pem-jwk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pem-jwk) to extract the components of the public/private keys like this:

```
const pem2jwk = require('pem-jwk').pem2jwk

console.log(pem2jwk(pemPublicKey));
OUTPUT:
{
  kty: '...',
  n: '...',
  e: '...'
}

console.log(pem2jwk(pemPrivateKey));
OUTPUT:
{
  kty: '...',
  n: '...',
  e: '...',
  d: '...',
  p: '...',
  q: '...',
  dp: '...',
  dq: '...',
  qi: '...'
}
```